# Django 3.1 fix Admin Category name to Categories

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How do I change some models name from "**Categorys**" to "**Categories**" on admin site in django version 3.1?

below is my code snippet

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    cat_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/categories', blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "category"
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

I run python manage.py makemigrations command and got a **No changes detected** response.

Please note that i inserted the lines of code below last hoping for changes to take effect but i still got a **No changes detected** response.

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "category"
    verbose_name_plural = "categories"
```

I also tried changing the category name max field from 50 to 100 like this

```
category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

and when i run the python manage.py makemigrations command i got the response below

```
$ python manage.py migrate

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, category, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying category.0002_auto_20211227_0931... OK
```

Comment: I think what you did is correct. But did you register your model properly in admin.py?

Comment: I don't see any coding mistake, you have set the verbose_name_plural correctly.  I had the same issue in the past. So what I did, I close my IDE, reopen the project and re-run the server. I don't know how but it worked properly.

Comment: @AkshayPawar I have managed to fix it. What has worked is placing the class meta and the two lines of code below directly under the class Category (models.Model) line..